# Conda Environment Execution Issue: Python Code Accessing Packages Outside Defined Environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm facing an issue where, despite having a Conda environment set up and the necessary packages installed within it, **when I execute Python code within the environment, it seems to be using some packages from outside the environment**. This is causing unexpected behavior and is preventing me to run a model with the appropriate PyTorch version. Can anyone help me understand the potential causes and how to resolve this issue?

Here are some details:

- I've activated my Conda environment using `conda activate <env>`.
- I've confirmed that the packages are installed within the Conda environment using `conda list`.
- The `which python` command shows the correct path within the Conda environment.
- I've checked my PATH variable, and the Conda environment comes before other directories

Using `python -v` and importing some packages to see that some of them (torch for ex) were of other versions than the one installed in the environment. *I have noticed that some of the packages installed in the environment are properly imported from `.conda/envs/env/...`.*

What could be causing this behavior, and how can I ensure that my Python code runs using the packages within my Conda environment?

If needed, I can provide the environment.yml file used to create the conda environment.